# Is it correct to use a comma in this equation?

Tags: equations, punctuation, typography, grammar

Consider:

```
Then, the sequence $k_i$ given by (3.38) is increasing and converges to 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:weired_equation}
k^\xi = k_1\times k_2 \times c \times d,
\end{equation}
where $c$ and $d$ are defined in the Theorem 2.
```

I have the questions:

1. What are the grammatical errors in the above piece?
2. Should a comma be used after the equation \eqref{eq:weired_eqution}.

Comment: @WillHunting I don't 100% agree with you, mathematical language has some specifics, and mathematical typography as well. IMHO, this question is boundary here, but still ok.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the comma is correct (see my answer). On the other hand, I think that (1) There should be no comma after `Then`, and (2) there should be no `the` before `Theorem 2` (you write `Theorem` with capital `T`, hence it is like a name). However, I'm not a native speaker, and one such should confirm what I say.

Comment: @tohecz: http://math.stackexchange.com exists `:-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no difference in punctuation whether you write the equation on display or inside the text.

So since there would be a comma if written inside the text, the comma is correct.

---

Considering the 1st question, see my comment. In the end, the piece can look like

```
Then the sequence $k_i$ given by (3.38) is increasing and converges to 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:weired_equation}
k^\xi = k_1\times k_2 \times c \times d,
\end{equation}
where $c$ and $d$ are defined in Theorem 2.
```

In the label, there's a typo and it should be `weird_equation`, but I did not correct this to avoid you problems with cross-referencing.